# iPhone: how to zoom only the image from scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, uiscrollview

I have this problem with ScrollView zoom. There are many articles about it but somehow I can't find proper explanation, tutorial or code snippet.

I have full screen scrollview and inside a fullscreen imageview. Inside imageview I load AspectFit images (they can be either vertical or horizontal, horizontal ones have black space above and under). When I make zoom I zoom not only the image but also the area around (the rest of imageview). Moreover, when I rotate simulator while in zoom the image goes to top-right corner instead of being centered like at start. Few pixels even go out of the screen.

I would really like to zoom only image instead of whole imageview or at least have the image centered all the time when zoomed.

Any help welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it's not the best code but works good for me for now, I will probably clean it a bit later. Posting here, maybe it will help someone :)

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                   pathForResource:someImage ofType:@"jpg"]];
CGFloat scale; 
    if (scrollView.frame.size.width < scrollView.frame.size.height) // portrait
        scale = scrollView.frame.size.width / img.size.width;
    if (scrollView.frame.size.width > scrollView.frame.size.height) // landscape
        scale = scrollView.frame.size.height / img.size.height;

imgView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, 
                           img.size.width*scale, img.size.height*scale);
imgView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width/2, scrollView.frame.size.height/2);

[imgView setImage:img];

[scrollView setZoomScale:scale];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PhotoScroller example; add this to layoutSubviews:

```
// center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen

CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = imageView.frame;

// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

// center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

imageView.frame = frameToCenter;
```

This won't help with zooming only the image but it'll keep it centered when you zoom it at least.

Comment: where exactly should I put it ? :) I just change images with imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:whichNext]; I don't really init any Rect with image. I just change the content of imageView.

Comment: You'd put this in layoutSubviews - it's fine if you don't initialize the UIImageView's frame when you create it, it takes on the size of the image you initialize it with (though if you give it a different image with a new size you should call `[sizeToFit]` to resize it). As you can see in the above, you're not changing its size in this case either; you're just changing its origin so it'll center itself as you zoom out.